# Como transformar essa consulta em uma JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

Tenho a seguinte consulta no banco de dados postgres:

```
select * from trabalha_projeto tp inner join Empregado e on
e.matricula = tp.empregado
```

como transforma-lá em uma consulta JPQL?
Estou com uma dificuldade para retornar os valores:

- Primeiro : por não saber formular a query com jpql
- Segundo: Devido ao fato de ter duas entidades java, e para relaciona-las possuir três tabelas no banco

As minhas duas entidades Empregado e Projeto viram as tabelas:
Projeto
Empregado
Empregado_Projeto(empregado_matricula,projetos_codigo)

Aqui estão minhas classes java:

**Classe Empregado**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "empregado_sequence", sequenceName = "empregado_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class Empregado implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "empregado_sequence")
    private int matricula;
    private String nome;
    private Double salario;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Projeto.class ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Projeto> projetos;

    public Empregado() {
    }
```

**Classe Projeto**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "projeto_sequence" , sequenceName = "projeto_sequence",
           allocationSize =  1 , initialValue = 1)
public class Projeto implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE , generator = "projeto_sequence")
    private int codigo;
    private String nome;

    public Projeto() {
    }
```

Como retornar todos os empregado que trabalham em um projeto usando um join?

Answer (score 1):

Em consultas objeto Relacionais HQL/JPQL, a consulta é feita baseado nas Classes e não nas tabelas do banco de dados, sem o nome das Classes/Campos fica difícil te passar com exatidão, porém seguindo a convenção, sua consulta seria algo assim:

```
from Projeto p join p.empregado
```

Caso a consulta não dê certo, confira o nome de suas Classes e o campo de join(empregado), também adicione a clausula de where caso a tenha.

Comment: Obrigado pela força, editei a pergunta para melhor esclarecer minha duvida.